# Elastic Phrase with stop words doesn't work

Tags: elasticsearch

I am facing problem with phrase and stop words

Settings.json

```
{
  "index": {
    "refresh_interval": "30s",
    "number_of_shards": 4,
    "number_of_replicas": 1,
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "default": {
          "type": "standard",
          "stopwords": "_english_"
        },
        "synonym_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "stopwords": "_english_",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "synonym_filter"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "synonym_filter": {
          "type": "synonym_graph",
          "lenient": true,
          "ignore_case": true,
          "expand": false,
          "synonyms": [
            "IVJ=>IVJ,Interactive Value Journey"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

when i use query time analyzer then phrases with stop words are not matched

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "asset.title": {
        "query": "RISE with Company",
        "analyzer": "synonym_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Returns no matches whenever there are stop words so essentially I need to consider stop words when it is phrase query but ignore them when it is multi match query.